# JavaScript Library - how to expose callback functions

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a JS library that creates an `iframe` with the requested content and also helps to facilitate the communication between the parent site and the `iframe`.

To communicate between the parent site and the `iframe` I'm using Post Messages. This works fine and I can do everything that I aim with this functionality. The idea I have is to "wrap" the `window.postMessage()` and `window.addEventListener('message', ...)` in my own library so that the site that is using this library would only be concerned with pushing and reading data. Also this helps me be sure that the correct validation is done on both `window.postMessage()` and `window.addEventListener('message', ...)`.

Using the library I have managed to expose a function for the site to push data to the `iframe`. However I haven't found a way to "expose" a callback that I can call when events are caught in the `window.addEventListener('message', ...)`.

**Sample Code:**

*Library*

```
export function createIframe(config) {
    ....
    readPostMessage();
}

let readPostMessage = () => {
    window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
        // validation and checks
        ...

        if(e.origin.match(regex)) {
            let data = e.data;
            switch(data.event) {
                case 'myTestCallback':
                    // ... call callback function?
                    callSomeFunctionDefinedByParent();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
};

export function pushData(data) {
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(data, '*');
}
```

Library is then built using webpack.

*Parent Site*

```
<html>
<body>
    <!-- iframe to be embedded in myDiv -->
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <button onclick="testPushData()">Test Push Data to Iframe</button>

    <script src="./my-library.js"></script>
    <script>
        // assuming that my-library.js exposes global variable myLibrary
        myLibrary.createIframe({
            element: '#myDiv',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
        });

        // works well
        testPushData() {
            myLibrary.pushData({event: 'pushDataTest'});
        }

        // parent define what happens when 'myTestCallback' is called...
        // something I had in mind... for example:
        myLibrary.on('myTestCallback', () => {
            //....
        });

        // or...
        myLibrary.myTestCallback = () => {
            //....
        });
    </script>
</html>
</body>
```

The code above is a simple bit of code to give an idea of what I have. My issue at the moment is to find a way to expose a callback to the parent which I can call when an event of type `'myTestCallback'` is posted to the parent site.

Since this is a library I'd like for the parent site to decide what should happen when a message is posted from the `iframe`. In this example I have 'myTestCallback' as an event type inside the `readPostMessage()` function. How would I go about allowing the parent site to define some function that the library would then call?

Comment: So the *relevant* question is really "How to communicate between an iframe and parent page [in JavaScript]?" Then it's just 'wrapping/hiding said method in a "callback"'.. FWIW: an iframe and parent page do *not* share the same `window` / JavaScript context.

Comment: Not really because I can achieve this by solely using `postMessage()` and then `'message'` event listener. I want to be able to handle all of that myself. I'd like to know a way how to enable the parent site of what should happen when the 'myTestCallback' is called. I updated the question to better explain myself.

Comment: Well where does the callback function come from, how would the caller of your library use it? Would they call `myLibrary.installCallback(function(){…})`, or would they pass it as an argument to `pushData`?

Comment: The callback function needs to be defined in the parent site. The caller would use it as the function to run after some event the happened in the `iframe`. And yes it should be something like `myLibrary.installCallback(function(){…})`, but not sure how to implement.

Comment: Well, if your `installCallback` takes a parameter (let's call it `cb`), then all you need to do is to store this somewhere and when needed call `cb()`. Or you would probably actually have, say, an array of callbacks and each could receive some data, so you'd do something like `cbArray.forEach( cb => cb(dataReturnedFromSomeCall) )`. You could store them in an object, if you want or even a more complex structure but the point is you have them somewhere and then you execute them by appending `()`. Or you do `.apply`/`.call`.

Comment: @vlaz Thanks, that makes things a bit clearer in my head. I'll try to implement something along those lines.

Comment: @vlaz and Bergi thanks for your comments. I was for some reason overthinking it (it's been a long day). I managed to solve it... didn't realise it was so simple. Updated my question - thanks again!

Comment: @DanielGrima You might want to [post an answer yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead of updating the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't think it was this simple but I managed to solve it thanks to the comments on the question.

So I've added an `.on` function in my library which enables the parent to add callbacks. These are stored in an object which are then called by name where necessary.

**Code:**

*Library*

```
export function on(eventName, callback) {
    callbacks[eventName] = callback;
}
```

Then called using:

```
callbacks['test']();
```

*Parent*

```
myLibrary.on('test', () => {
    console.log('parent callback function!');
});
```

I implemented the `.on` function this way so that I can pass multiple callbacks to the library.